# Gitlab pipeline fails because of wrong Node.js version on the shared windows runner

Tags: node.js, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

When I try to run my build job it fails on the windows build stage since the Node.js version on the runner is v12.10.0, when it should be v18.7.0.

Is it possible to set a specific Node.js version on the windows shared runner to fix this issue?

I have the following configuration in my .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: node:18.7.0

before_script:  
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install
  - node -v

stages:
  - build

.build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build

build-linux:
  extends: .build
  tags:
    - linux
  artifacts:
    name: "Linux build"
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - dist

build-windows:
  extends: .build
  tags:
    - windows
  artifacts:
    name: "Windows build"
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - dist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by creating `.win-build` which contains `choco upgrade nodejs -y` and then adding it to `extends` in the `build-windows` stage.

```
.win-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - choco upgrade nodejs -y
    - npm install --progress=false
    - npm run build

build-windows:
  extends: .win-build
  tags:
    - windows
  artifacts:
    name: "Windows build"
    expire_in: 1 hour
    paths:
      - dist
```